# Dynamic color based on condition LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, dynamic-binding, svg, path

i want to fill the svg color based on condition

JS :

```
get OpptColorIcon() {
    const colors = this._listOpp.map(opp => {
        return opp.Scoring === "weak" ? "#FF8C00" : "#A52A2A";
    });

    return colors;
}
```

html :

```
<tbody>
                <template if:true={searchable} for:each={searchable} for:item="opp">
                    <template if:false={opp.isHidden}>
                        <tr key={opp.Id} class="box-shadow font-family">
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left width-10 padding-left-10" role="gridcell">
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox" checked={opp.isChecked} onclick={handleSelect}
                                    data-id={opp.Id}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                {opp.NomPrenom}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                <lightning-formatted-date-time value={opp.Date} year="numeric" month="numeric"
                                    day="numeric" time-zone="UTC">
                                </lightning-formatted-date-time>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                {opp.Offre}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                {opp.Marche}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                <lightning-formatted-date-time value={opp.DateEffet} year="numeric" month="numeric"
                                    day="numeric" time-zone="UTC">
                                </lightning-formatted-date-time>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                {opp.Prime}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={opp.displayHourglass}>
                                </lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                                {opp.HistoriqueDate}
                                <div class="link-style" data-id={opp.Id} onclick={handleHistoriqueRelance}>
                                    {opp.displayText}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-text-align_left padding-5">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                                    fill="none">
                                    <path data-id={opp.id}
                                        d="M7.88867 15.5C3.81417 15.5 0.506226 12.2493 0.398874 8.20051L0.388671 0.499999L7.88867 0.5C12.031 0.5 15.3887 3.85808 15.3887 8C15.3887 12.1424 12.0306 15.5 7.88867 15.5Z"
                                        fill={OpptColorIcon} />
                                </svg>
```

it worked when i have 1 opportunity and it failed when i have more than 1 opporunity
I couldn't do `fill={OpptColorIcon[opp.Id]}` in order to test on all opportunity and change the js like

```
get OpptColorIcon() {
        return scoring === 'weak' ? '#FF8C00' : '#A52A2A';
}
```

It doesn't work either ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color property should be available for each opportunity record in the list `searchable` which is used in for each loop

When you are preparing the `searchable` list, set the `iconColor` property

```js
this.searchable.forEach((opp)=>{
    opp.iconColor = opp.Scoring === "weak" ? "#FF8C00" : "#A52A2A";
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
    <path data-id={opp.id}
        d="M7.88867 ..."
        fill={opp.iconColor} />
</svg>
```